# How to load multiple files successively with ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a large text file with some 2 million records, when I load it with ajax it takes a lot of time, I would like to split it and load the split files successively.

[image: Successive ajax loads]

I use this code to load that single large file that I want to split

```
$.ajax({
    url: "singleLargeFile.csv",
    async: true,
    success: function () {
        process();
        },
    error: function(e) {
        var errorMsg = e? (e.status + ' ' + e.statusText) : "";
        console.log(errorMsg);
        },
    dataType: "text"
    });
```

Is there a way to load multiple files and each one after being loaded triggers both its callback and the loading of the next file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is a function in jquery `$.when()` I used it like this :

```
var loadFile1 = $.ajax({
    url: "smallerFile1.csv",
    async: true,
    success: function () {
        process1();
        },
    error: function(e) {
        var errorMsg = e? (e.status + ' ' + e.statusText) : "";
        console.log(errorMsg);
        },
    dataType: "text"
   });


$.when(loadFile1).then(function(){
    var loadFile2 = $.ajax({
        url: "smallerFile2.csv",
        async: true,
        success: function () {
            process2();
            },
        error: function(e) {
            var errorMsg = e? (e.status + ' ' + e.statusText) : "";
            console.log(errorMsg);
            },
        dataType: "text"
        });
    });
```

Now the process1 is executed when the first file is loaded and then the second load is triggered and so on